# Greens function of the equation $(\alpha^2 \Delta^2 - \Delta + \beta^2)u = 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the equation 
$(\alpha^2 \Delta^2 - \Delta + \beta^2)u = 0$, 
where $\Delta = \partial/\partial x^2 + \partial/\partial ^2$ and $u(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Is anyone aware of the greens function of the above equation? For the case $\alpha =0$, above equation reduces to the Helmholtz equation with $\frac{1}{2 \pi} K_0(\beta r)$ being the Greens function ($r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and $K_0$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind). But I am interested in the case $\alpha \neq 0$. Can some one help in calculating the Greens function of the equation?

Comment: Do you maybe know the Greens function of $\Delta^2$? Usually you can construct a full Greens function if you know the Greens function of the summands.

Comment: The Greens function of $\Delta^2 u = 0$ is $\frac{1}{8 \pi} r^2 \ln r$. However, is it true that : "Usually you can construct a full Greens function if you know the Greens function of the summands". Could you point me to some specific references?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your equation for $\alpha \neq 0$ as
\begin{equation*}
Lu=\{(\Delta -\frac{1}{2\alpha ^{2}})^{2}+\beta ^{2}-\frac{1}{4\alpha ^{4}}%
\}u=0
\end{equation*}
and your Green's function is proportional to the imaginary part of
\begin{equation*}
<\mathbf{x}|\frac{1}{-i\varepsilon -\beta ^{2}+\frac{1}{4\alpha ^{2}}-(k^{2}+%
\frac{1}{2\alpha ^{2}})^{2}}|\mathbf{y}>\\=\frac{1}{(2\pi )^{2}}\int_{\mathbb{R%
}^{2}}d\mathbf{k}\exp [i\mathbf{k\cdot }(\mathbf{x-y)}]\frac{1}{%
-i\varepsilon -\beta ^{2}+\frac{1}{4\alpha ^{2}}-(k^{2}+\frac{1}{2\alpha ^{2}
})^{2}}
\end{equation*}
The integral seems to be doable since there are only pole contributions.